# How do I call - (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated from another method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

It is possible to call one method from inside another. I've implemented this function

```
- (void)pickAndDecodeFromSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) sourceType
```

I want to call following method inside the above one.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking... the question is.. well not there.  Nonetheless:

What I think you're asking: "How do I call viewDidAppear from within another method...?"

```
- (void)pickAndDecodeFromSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
 ...
    [myController viewDidAppear:YES]; //Simply call it on whatever instance of a controller you have
 ...
}
```

If the question was actually "How do I override viewDidAppear?" then this is it:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     //YOUR STUFF
     //GOES HERE
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always call the delegate methods directly:

```
[self viewDidAppear:YES]
```

Called from inside your method should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but from the nature of your question I am guessing you are new to Obj-C so I strongly suggest reading [Introduction to The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) if you have not already.  If you have, great!  What you are looking for is most likely under [Objects Classes and Messaging - Object Messaging - Message Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW6)